# Displaying editable html in an edittext

Tags: android, html

I have tried Html.fromHtml () method to get spanned text to display in edit-text but since it does not support tables and other useful html tags its of no use for me. I am working on mail client and want to display editable html just like gmail and other client app do when replying to mail.

Comment: I am confused on what is being asked. To set the text of an EditText field you would apply the method **setText()** and pass in the text or html you want to be editable as a param, then the text should be editable as it would be in an EditText field. What is the specific issue you are facing in accomplishing what you are trying to do?

Comment: Issue is with displaying html in edittext supporting all html tags or at least supporting table and other basic tags . As Html. fromHtml () doesnt support all tags i want to know if there is an alternative providing the solution